org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'null':Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
I'm working on a Spring context with rest Servlet and I'm getting this error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'null': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientiDAO': No qualifying bean of type 'it.northwind.app.dao.impl.ClientiDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Servlet
package it.northwind.app.servlet;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import it.northwind.app.dao.impl.ClientiDAO;
import it.northwind.app.model.Cliente;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@WebServlet("/api/clienti")
public class ClientiRestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Autowired
    private ClientiDAO clientiDAO;



    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            List<Cliente> clienti = clientiDAO.getAllClientiByIdRecDesc();
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(clienti));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cliente record = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), Cliente.class);

        try {
            if (record.getIdRec() != null) {
                record = clientiDAO.updateCliente(record);
            } else {
                record = clientiDAO.insertCliente(record);
            }
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(record));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Integer idRec = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("ID_CLIENTE"));

        try {
            clientiDAO.deleteClienteByIdRec(idRec);
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT); // 204 No Content for successful deletion
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setClientiDAO(ClientiDAO clientiDAO) {
        this.clientiDAO = clientiDAO;
    }
}

Spring Config:
package it.northwind.app.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("it.northwind.app")
@EnableJpaRepositories("it.northwind.app.dao.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SpringConfiguration {



    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUsername("ZRB_ERP");
        dataSource.setPassword("ZRB_ERP");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("it.northwind.app.model");
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBean.getObject());
        return txManager;
    }
}

This is the DAO that is null when set:
package it.northwind.app.dao.impl;

import it.northwind.app.model.Cliente;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

@Repository("ClientiDAO")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class ClientiDAO extends BaseDAO<Cliente> {

    public List<Cliente> getAllClientiByIdRecDesc(){
        // Using HQL to get all Cliente records ordered by idRec in descending order
        Query<Cliente> query = getSession().createQuery("select c from Cliente c order by idRec desc", Cliente.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Cliente insertCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        // Generating a random ID for demonstration purposes
        Integer idRec = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100000);
        cliente.setIdRec(idRec.longValue());

        // Persisting the cliente object with Hibernate
        getSession().save(cliente);
        return cliente;
    }

    public Cliente updateCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        // Updating the cliente object with Hibernate
        getSession().update(cliente);
        return cliente;
    }

    public void deleteClienteByIdRec(Integer idRec) {
        // Deleting the cliente record by ID using HQL
        Query<?> query = getSession().createQuery("delete from Cliente where idRec = :idRec");
        query.setParameter("idRec", idRec);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

}

BaseDAO:
package it.northwind.app.dao.impl;

import it.northwind.app.dao.IBaseDAO;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class BaseDAO<T> implements IBaseDAO<T> {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(T transientInstance) {
        Session sessione =getSession();

            sessione.saveOrUpdate(transientInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T persistentInstance) {
        Session sessione = getSession();
        sessione.remove(persistentInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void merge(T detachedInstance) {

    }

    @Override
    public T findById(Integer identifier, Class<?> persistentClass) {
        return (T) this.getSession().get(persistentClass, identifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Session getSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}


This is where I'm getting this error:
  @Autowired public void setClientiDAO(ClientiDAO clientiDAO) { this.clientiDAO = clientiDAO; }
it says that clientiDAO has null value, the DAOs extend basedao which implements IBaseDAO interface please I tried solutions offered by chatgpt but were useless, thank you
I tried various solution, by mapping servlet elsewhere or removing various annotations but didn't work

Can you share the spring boot main class?

I’m not using spring boot just spring

Try it.northwind.app.dao.impl.*

it doesn't find the package, with the repository name that I used, on hover, the IDE suggests the right package
